# IndexError: list index out of range.how can i remove this error?

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/codes/myprog.pyc", line 11, in <module>
    device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir+'28*')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

list index out of range.how can i remove this error?

Comment: Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and improve your question. Based on current state of your question it is not possible to help you.

Comment: check this link for code that i am using.http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2014/05/11/android-linux-raspberry-pi-bluetooth-communication/

Comment: Hmm, last time I saw the number 28 like this I was writing a program to read the temperatures of DS18B20 temperature sensors on a raspberry pi, it would be useful to see what's actually going on here

Answer (score 0):

`glob.glob(base_dir+'28*')` will return an list of directories/files based on your wild card if none of the directories/files found it will return an empty list like this []. So if you will try to access the 0th element of empty list you will face this `IndexError`. just check if your path is correct. 
I think your are missing **os.sep**

Just change this line :

```
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir+'28*')[0]
```

To this :

```
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir+ os.sep +'28*')[0]
```

hope this helps